# Adding all lengths of sublists

Tags: python, list

I can print out the length of maximum length of the sublist with this below

```
print(len(max(list, key=len)))
```

Is there a simple way of finding all the length of sublists?
For instance, if the sublists have

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2]
```

I want to output

> 8

And if sublists have

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2], [3]
```

then I want to output

> 9

Comment: Note there are multiple approaches to this problem. If i remember correctly, your code is the fastest approach but `max(map(len, sublists))` also works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(sum(map(len, sublists)))
```

Comment: If you throw parenthesis around the `sum()` call, this will also work in Python 3 (and continue to work in Python 2).

Comment: @Kevin It also helped me hit the 30 character minimum without that dot in my answer